# Before the Flood: Why did the TARDIS malfunction and take the Doctor back 30 minutes?

Tags: doctor-who

In *Before the Flood*, the Doctor tries to go to a random location to avoid his eventual death, but the TARDIS malfunctions and takes him 30 minutes back.

Why did it malfunction and take him 30 min back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *The Doctor's Wife*, we learned that TARDIS is sentient. Also, she told that when she doesn't obey Doctor, she takes Doctor to a place of importance.

From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/32-4.htm) of *The Doctor's Wife*:

> DOCTOR: You didn't always take me where I wanted to go.
>   IDRIS: No, but I always took you where you needed to go.
>   DOCTOR: You did.

So, it's likely that TARDIS intentionally took Doctor 30 minutes back because it already knew the future (yeah, Timey-Wimey stuff).

Comment: We know that the TARDIS does have knowledge of the future from that same episode because she states that she has archives of console rooms that the Doctor hasn't created yet.